# Using a relay to turn on and off really low voltage circuit

Tags: arduino, relay, low-voltage

I want to build a thermostat for my fireplace. I want to use my Arduino to turn it ON and OFF.
The fireplace has got a switcher on the wall and I have measured it and the voltage different from one side of the switch to the other side is 0,238V. It seems pretty low but that is what it is.

I bought [this relay](http://tinkbox.ph/sites/tinkbox.ph/files/downloads/KEYES%205V%20Relay%20Module%20KY-019.pdf) that I am going to be able to use with my Arduino.

I know relays are usually used to turn ON/OFF circuits that are running at a higher voltage. In this case, my relay will have to run a circuit that is running in a much less voltage. Will the relay do what I need it to do? or it will actually create a higher voltage in the fireplace circuit?

[image]

Comment: 0.2 V as voltage seen across a switch that is not on the same circuit board almost certainly means you're not measuring the right thing – maybe you're looking at DC voltage, but the device observes the switch with AC? Maybe you measured with the switch *closed* instead of *open*?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It could be a 'millivolt' thermostat system which would be powered by a thermopile in the fireplace and uses very low DC voltages.

Comment: @brhans but then let that voltage get exposed to long leads in a non-RF-controlled environment?

Comment: I get how thermopiles are used for flame-failure detection, but I struggle to see how they could be used to control a burner that was cold - either you'd have to have a 'normally open' gas valve (!) or some other way to kick it into life (which is what flame-failure systems do).  Occam tells me, as he told @MarcusMüller, that the measurement's bogus.

Comment: The thermopile is "powered" by the pilot light, which is always on. This also makes it fail-safe, because if the pilot goes out, it's no longer possible to activate the main valve. And despite the low voltage, such circuits are also very low impedance, which makes them relatively immune to EMI.

Comment: The millivolt thermopile system is usually for the pilot (so the pilot is always on regarless of what AC mains is doing). The main gas is activated by a solenoid, probably connected to AC mains (doesn't have to be).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that relay module will be fine. It provides an isolated contact closure that is compatible with your fireplace's millivolt control circuit.

The point of a relay is that it isolates the control circuit from the circuit being controlled. It doesn't matter whether the latter involves higher or lower voltages — or even the same voltage.